# WPF How to cast ListBox.ItemsSource into ObservableCollection<some dynamic type>

Tags: c#, behavior, covariance

I have written a Behavior which allows to reorder a ListBox. To work properly the ListBox's ItemsSource has to be an ObservableCollection<...>, so I can call the Move(from,to)-method.

My problem is:
How can I cast the ListBox.ItemsSource into a ObservableCollection.

I already tried:

```
ObservableCollection<object> test = listBox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<object>;
```

which does not work, because ObservableCollection doesn't support covariance.

Comment: Is your question because you know `listBox.ItemsSource` is *some* type of `IList<T>`, but you just don't know what at runtime?

Comment: I can get the type of the List only at runtime.

Comment: EDIT: I need the list to be an ObservableCollection<T> instead of IList<T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the method you'd like to call, `ObservableCollection<T>.Move`, you can use simple reflection:

```
var move = listBox.ItemsSource
                  .GetType()
                  .GetMethod("Move");
if (move != null)
{
    move.Invoke(listBox.ItemsSource, new[] { old, new });
}
else
{
    // IList fallback?
}
```

Comment: I'm using the IList-Approach by default, but your answer is a (dirty) nice approach, too!